# Swift и использование нескольких классов из разных файлов

Tags: swift, классы

У меня есть несколько классов в разных файлах.

```
1.swift
2.swift
и т.д.
```

у меня открыт проект в xcode, и я хочу использовать какие-то классы из первого, а какие-то из второго, в своем главном файле проекта. Например, это GameScene.swift

Как это вообще реализовывается?

В php нужно инклюдить файлы, а потом наследовать класс. 
В C# есть пространство имен, по ним я вытаскавал методы из другого файла с классом.

Как я заметил, в swift вроде нету пространств имен, или я их просто не заметил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если файлы 1.swift и 2.swift лежат в одном пакете с GameScene, то нет необходимости подключать файлы, вы можете просто использовать классы и функции описаные в этих файлах.

Comment: так все просто ?